# Custom runner for a test method, not at class level - Is it possible?

Tags: java, junit, powermock, junit-runner, powermockrunner

Is it possible to specify a `custom runner` per test method within a test class? That is:

```
Class SomeTests {

public void test1() {

}

public void test2() {
}


// For this test only, is it possible
// to specify a different runner, for 
// example : `PowerMockRunner`
public void test3() {  
}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `@ExtendWith` annotation for JUnit5?

Comment: @Progman: Thanks for your reply. I am using Junit 4. Hence asking if it is possible to specify Runner per test method basis.